# PHP Facebook SDK - how to post friends profile picture to the wall?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, image

I am trying

```
$attachment = array('message' => "message",
            'name' => 'name',
            'caption' => "caption",
            'link' => 'some URL address',
            'picture' => "https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID_NUMBER/picture");
```

But the post on the wall is not posted. When I pick some other image and set up the URL, it works well.
This `https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID_NUMBER/picture` returns me user's profile picture in the application without any problems, but when I am trying to post it to the wall, then it doesn't work.

So - how could I get the URL of the user's profile picture and post it to the wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID_NUMBER/picture
```

redirects to original image url, which you can get using `get_headers` function of PHP. something like this you can do:

```
$headers = get_headers("https://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/picture?type=large");
$image_loc = $headers[5]; //if not work, check at what index actual url is coming though it works for me
```

and then use this $image_loc url for posting on facebook.

Comment: Thanks for your message Smita. I've tried your way and yea, I got the image. But it seems that Facebook doesn't allow to post it to the wall - I am getting this error message: `(#100) FBCDN image is not allowed in stream:`. Any idea, how to post there the profile picture? Likely, I will need to create a new image...

Comment: Ok then I think, you will need to download the image to your server and then put your server image url up there.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, but

'picture' => "https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID_NUMBER/picture");

should show the PROFILE_ID's pic in the post...  I tried and got that, in fact it shows the pic of any user, not necessarily my friend :)

Try using the user's access token with the picture link, might work ..

Comment: Yea, maybe can be a problem in the access_token, I will try it with.